# Setting speed factor in a timer class?

Tags: c++, sdl

I have the following timer class :

```
class Timer
{
    private:
    unsigned int curr,prev;
    float factor;
    float delta;

    public:
    Timer(float FrameLockFactor)
    {
        factor = FrameLockFactor;
    }

    ~Timer()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        curr = SDL_GetTicks();
        delta = (curr - prev) * (1000.f / factor);
        prev = curr;
    }

    float GetDelta() 
    {
        return delta;
    }
};
```

And i use it like this :

```
//Create a timer and lock at 60fps
Timer timer(60.0f);

while()
{
    float delta;
    float velocity = 4.0f;

    timer.Update();

    delta = timer.GetDelta();

    sprite.SetPosition( sprite.GetVector() + Vector2(0.0,velocity * delta) );
    sprite.Draw();
}
```

But there is a big problem : My game runs way too slow for a program that is supposed to run at 60frames per second and the same test code runs smooth when not using frame indepented movement , so there must be something wrong with my code.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `delta` is supposed to be a count of frames, shouldn't it be calculated as

```
delta = (curr - prev) * (factor / 1000.f);
```

Comment: Thanks , that's better. Although after some research i've found that it is indeed better to have fixed frame rate in games instead frame independent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you are trying to do with your code. Especially the line `delta = (curr - prev) * (1000.f / factor);` does not make sense as far as I can see.

If I understand this correctly you are trying to calculate how much time has passed since the last update and translate this into milliseconds per frame. What units are you using?

I don't know what is returned by `SDL_GetTicks();`. Is this the number of processor or real clock ticks, which is returned? In case it is returning real clock ticks, the `(curr-prev)` part will most often be zero, since you have to do multiple updates per frame for this to work.

If it is not returning real clock ticks, why are you multiplying by `1000f`. Where does this factor come from?

With code like this, it is often very important to take care of round-off errors, so I am guessing that your problem lies somewhere in this area. Although without additional information I cannot tell what your actuall problem may be.

Comment: Im multiplying all velocities with the delta value in order to achieve frame indepented movement by using this formula : (currTicks-PrevTicks) / 1000.0f. But now i also want to be able to limit the frames by a variable factor , to say , 60fps.